# Can you append values to an appendbuffer and then immediately read from that same buffer?

Tags: unity, hlsl, memory-efficiency, compute-shader

I am looking to achieve the following: I have a compute shader that receives a `Texture2D` as input, where a small percentage of the pixels in the texture are white. The location of the white pixels are unpredictable for any given frame. I want to read the depth value at these white pixels and store them in memory. I can't put them in a `RWStructuredBuffer` because there is no way to prevent each thread from overriding another thread when storing values to the buffer. Of course I could assign each thread its own position in the buffer, but then this would include **all** non-white pixels. I only want to store the values from white pixels, so the buffer would be much smaller in size than the texture. I can achieve this with an append buffer, simply by having only the white pixels append to the `appendbuffer`. But I don't know how I can then subsequently **read** from that `appendbuffer` in another compute shader. Is that possible?

For further context on the end objective, please see my other (currently unanswered) post [asking about the most efficient way to calculate signed distance field (SDF) for pixel subsamples](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/13837/5349).